# Matlab: For Loop for Different Titles

Tags: matlab, plot

In MATLAB, I am generating different plots through a for loop and I have a string array,

```
 s = {'Indiana','Alabama','Texas'}
```

and the goal is to print out each string in the array as a separate title for each plot.

So for plot 1 is titled Indiana, plot 2 is titled Alabama, plot 3 is titled Texas.

Thanks,

Amanda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i from 1 to 3
   plot p = <whatever you plot is> 
   title(s[i])
   set(p)
```

something of this nature is what you are looking for